# Confusion over constructing interpolation functions from tables

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, interpolation

Suppose I have a set of functions:

```
f[x_] := x^2;

g[x_] := (f[x])^2 +2*f[x];

h[x_] := 2*f[x]+5*g[x];
```

I tabulate the first two functions over `x` such that

```
ftab1 = Table[{x,f[x]},{x,0,5,0.5}];

gtab1 = Table[{x,g[x]},{x,0,5,0.5}];
```

then use them to construct a table for `h[x]`, i.e.

```
ftotal1 = Table[{x,2*ftab1[[j,2]]+5*gtab1[[j,2]]},{j,1,Length[ftab1]}];
```

and finally interpolate this table to obtain a function,

```
func1 = Interpolation[ftotal1];
```

I then construct  tables again as above, but replacing `x` with `func1[x]`, such that

```
ftab2 = Table[{x,f[func1[x]]},{x,0,5,0.5}];

gtab2 = Table[{x,g[func1[x]]},{x,0,5,0.5}];

ftotal2 = Table[{x,2*ftab2[[j,2]]+5*gtab2[[j,2]]},{Length[ftab2]}];
```

and then finally interpolate the result again to obtain a new function

```
func2 = Interpolation[ftotal2];
```

Alternatively, I simply tabulate `h[x]` straight away, i.e.

```
htab1 = Table[{x,h[x]},{x,0,5,0.5}];
```

then interpolate this

```
hfunc1 = Interpolation[htab1];
```

Following the same procedure, I then tabulate `h` again, replacing `x` with `hfunc1`,

```
htab2 = Table[{x,h[hfunc1[x]]},{x,0,5,0.5}];
```

an then finally interpolate this to get

```
hfunc2 = Interpolation[htab2];
```

What I find is that, if I plot a graph of the interpolation functions,  `hfunc1 = func1`, *however* `hfunc2 ≠ func2`. Why is this the case? Is it something to do with the precision errors that are accumulated in the two different methods and how Mathematica handles them?

Comment: Try adding `InterpolationOrder -> 4` to `Interpolation[]`. You are in effect trying to approximate a quartic polynomial with piecewise cubics, so no surprise that there is some error.

Comment: @J.M.  Thanks, that seems to have worked. Will this kind of thing work in a more general case

Comment: As a rather famous book on numerical computing once put it, "higher order does not mean higher accuracy". In this case, increasing the interpolation order worked because your actual function is a polynomial, but if the function were transcendental...

Comment: @J.M.          Ah, that's frustrating as I have a Runge-Kutta routine that I'm struggling to get to work precisely because of this problem.

Comment: ...and that's why one should always try to come up with a minimal example that still has most of the features of the original problem. ;)

Comment: @J.M.          Yes, you're right. Apologies, my example was over simplified!